# Mapping and displaying returned data from json in vue app

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am returnig json from my api.

```
      dietPhase: (state) => state.dietPhase,
```

I have this in state which returns 3 types of meals - breakfast, dinner and supper.
I've filtered it to return only breakfast type. Now I'm having issue with mapping this.
I want it to only return ingriedients name and unit from this json. How can I do this, and display it on my html?

```
computed - 

breakfast() {
      return _.filter(this.dietPhase.meals, ({ type }) => type == "breakfast");
    },
```

```
  mounted() {
    this.setSlug(this.dietPhaseSlug);
    this.fetch();
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions({
      setSlug: "dietPhase/setSlug",
      fetch: "dietPhase/fetch",
    }),
```

```
[
   {
      "id":"34649fd9-88a5-4773-b890-3253f964ab7b",
      "description":"Chicken and veg",
      "type":"breakfast",
      "ingredients":[
         {
            "name":"Chicken",
            "weight":"65",
            "unit":"65g",
            "type":"tag",
            "type_id":"5b32d5b3-dd88-459e-80ca-9c9c4d0891c3"
         },
   {
            "name":"Vegetables",
            "weight":"95",
            "unit":"95g",
            "type":"product_group",
            "type_id":"b5fad2f4-25e6-45d2-9d2a-4202cbfaef40"
         }
      ]
   },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over the filtered list and then again to get the ingredients' names and units for every meal item.

To render the resulting list properly, you can use two `v-for`, an outer one for the meal items and an inner one for the ingredients:

```js
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data(){
    return{
     dietPhase: {
       meals: [
         {
           "id":"34649fd9-88a5-4773-b890-3253f964ab7b",
           "description":"Chicken and veg",
           "type":"breakfast",
           "ingredients": [
             {
               "name":"Chicken",
               "weight":"65",
               "unit":"65g",
               "type":"tag",
               "type_id":"5b32d5b3-dd88-459e-80ca-9c9c4d0891c3"
             },
             {
               "name":"Vegetables",
               "weight":"95",
               "unit":"95g",
               "type":"product_group",
               "type_id":"b5fad2f4-25e6-45d2-9d2a-4202cbfaef40"
             }
           ]
         },
       ]
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    breakfast(){
      return _.filter(this.dietPhase.meals, ({ type }) => type == "breakfast")
        .map(meal => {
          const ingredients = meal.ingredients.map(ingredient => (
            {name:ingredient.name, unit:ingredient.unit}
          ));
          return {...meal, ingredients}
        });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>id</td>
        <td>description</td>
        <td>type</td>
        <td>ingredients</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(meal,i) in breakfast" :key="i">
        <td>{{meal.id}}</td>
        <td>{{meal.description}}</td>
        <td>{{meal.type}}</td>
        <td>
          <ul>
            <li v-for="(ingredient,j) in meal.ingredients" :key="j">
              {{ingredient.name}} {{ingredient.unit}}
            </li>
          </ul>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: How do I display this in my vue? I hold this in a computed
When I put {{breakfast}} in html, it returns entire json and it's not mapped. How do I target the mapped meal inside this?

Comment: @Dave you mean rendering it? And how is it "not mapped"?

Comment: Yes, how to render it properly in html.

Comment: How exactly do you want to render it? Like showing the list of meals and in each one it's ingredients list?

Comment: I just want it like this 
a list with v-for
{{ingredient.name}} {{ingredient.unit}}

Comment: @Dave I updated the answer with a suitable solution to render the list

Comment: The list v-for gives me a blank screen for some reason on my page. Why is this happening? I think I can't have meal.ingredients, because I will have the  same computed for dinner and supper also.

Comment: How are you exactly rendering the other computed properties?

Comment: See this link please https://imgur.com/sYFsWa2
I have not rendered any of them in html yet.